# Goals are not showing in Experience Editor when setting up a Test in Sitecore 9.3

Tags: content-testing, goals, marketing-definitions

I have created a new Goal in Sitecore’s Marketing Control Panel to track a certain page visit and successfully deployed it. Now I want to use that goal to measure an experience effect for my AB Test, but for some reason it doesn’t appear in the "Test Objective" dropdown list.

I have made sure that everything is published, indexes are up-to-date and marketing definitions are deployed. What else could be preventing a Goal from being available for a Test setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, ensure that your goal is marked as a Goal, i.e. *“Is Goal - indicates that the page event is a goal”* checkbox in the **Options** section should be ticked off.

In case of a multilingual setup check that your goal is created and deployed for all relevant language variants, otherwise, Sitecore will filter out the available goals based on the viewing language. This might explain why you don’t see your newly created goal in Experience Editor.

Comment: It appeared to be that the English GB language is set as default one for my site and my goal was initially created in the English GB language as per the default settings in Sitecore. So, I needed to create another language variant for my goal in the English EN! After adding the English EN language version to the goal and deploying it, I can see this goal in the "Test Objective" dropdown.